# Using NPM packages without Webpack

Tags: node.js, npm

I am used to using NPM packages with Webpack, but I'm wondering how you're supposed to use NPM packages **without** Webpack.
I know how to install packages. I just don't know how to use them, since you can't just import modules in plain js.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: What do you want to do with npm?? You know exacly what npm is??

Comment: Yes, I know what NPM is :). As I said, I'm used to work with NPM and Webpack. But I'm trying to understand how NPM is used besides Webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack compiles a bunch of javascript files and combines them into a single one for web distribution. NPM downloads javascript files through packages.

Here's some scenarios where you might use NPM without webpack

1. You are doing Node.js server-side javascript development. There's no webpack here
2. You are using a webpack alternative like rollup or browserify
3. You directly do anything else with the files npm downloads. Maybe you concatenate, throw them in a Makefile or maybe you expose node_modules directly to the world and reference their full paths directly.

Most of my web and server-side development is *without* webpack.

Comment: So what is your workflow actually? Did you write a server to run your html and js files in the browser?

Comment: @TheCat  I do a lot of different things. Nothing I can quickly sum up. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to learn/achieve and based on that you might get more directed help.

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't import in plain  js?

If you correctly define the package entry point like
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",

Those files can be plain ES6 javascript with named exports or export default, and you can import them after intalling your package with regular import.

You don't need webpack nor babel to make an mpm module. Just put in any folder the files you want to distribute, specifying the main entry point and export elements on that file.

Now... in an angular or react application for example, they may install your component and will use babel and webpack to first transpile your component to ES5 with babel, and then bundle your code together with the rest of their app using webpack.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't know you could export/import in vanilla js :o

Comment: @TheCat did you check ESM? it worth giving it a try https://github.com/standard-things/esm

Comment: It isn’t obvious how one specifies entry and export points. You should show a concrete example. import statements will be rejected outside a module, and modules are not present without webpack (by default).

Comment: @Cybernetic maybe isn't very clear in the official documentation, anyway, in this article, they explain how the import works to find the main entry point if defined, and what they do if it's not present.
https://bytearcher.com/articles/main-property-in-package.json-defines-entry-point/
You have the official documentation
- https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points
and just below that section, the section of the "Main entry point export".

Answer (score 0):

For front-end, not node.js but still NPM modules.

HTML can import directly ES6 modules but the file must be in .mjs format and provide `export default`, `Module.exports` in regular .js file wont't work. This is not a common thing and you'll run into problems if there are subdependencies that don't use ES6 modules. If you find a module that supports it. i.e. `some-module`

`npm install some-module`

And in the same directory next to `node_modules` create index.html pointing straight to the modular bundle

```html
<h1>I'm HTML</h1>
<script type="module">
  import SomeModule from './node_modules/some-module/bundle.mjs';
  const mod = new SomeModule();
  mod.doStuff();
</script>
```

Here's an article about this https://medium.com/passpill-project/files-with-mjs-extension-for-javascript-modules-ced195d7c84a

Answer (score -3):

```
npm init
```

To create a package.json file

```
npm install --save <package>
```

To install a package and save it in the package.json file

Comment: I know how to install packages. I just don't know how to use them, since you can't just import modules in plain js. I believe you should use node to serve your files, but I haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: const package = require('package');

Comment: Sorry I think that's not the question